# in my global.asax, can I output the current route/action being fired?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

in my global.asax, can I output the current route/action being fired?

this is the debug something.

Answer (score 3):

Not without some work.  Try plugging in [Phil Haack's Route Debugger](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx), it might do what you need and save you some time.

Answer (score 0):

Global.asax doesn't have access to the response stream, so you cant write on a page directly. You could store the output in the Session, and if it exists, write it to the page in the master page, or you could simply log to a logging service like elmah, or the windows application log.

```
RequestContext.RouteData.Values
```

should give you the information you need.